# Task :react-native-webview:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, gradle

I keep getting this error, when I try running my React Native application after installing the react-native.webview package. Please what could I be doing wrong.

```
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 1135 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 busy Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details

> Task :react-native-webview:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :react-native-webview:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
79 actionable tasks: 14 executed, 65 up-to-date
C:\Projects\React-Native\FUNAI\node_modules\react-native-webview\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\webview\RNCWebViewModule.java:276: error: cannot find symbol
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                                                    ^
  symbol:   variable Q
  location: class VERSION_CODES
Note: C:\Projects\React-Native\FUNAI\node_modules\react-native-webview\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\webview\RNCWebViewManager.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Projects\React-Native\FUNAI\node_modules\react-native-webview\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\webview\RNCWebViewManager.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-webview:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 37s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
C:\Projects\React-Native\FUNAI\node_modules\react-native-webview\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\webview\RNCWebViewModule.java:276: error: cannot find symbol
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                                                    ^
  symbol:   variable Q
  location: class VERSION_CODES
Note: C:\Projects\React-Native\FUNAI\node_modules\react-native-webview\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\webview\RNCWebViewManager.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Projects\React-Native\FUNAI\node_modules\react-native-webview\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\webview\RNCWebViewManager.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-webview:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 37s

    at makeError (C:\Projects\React-Native\FUNAI\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at Promise.all.then.arr (C:\Projects\React-Native\FUNAI\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I also have the same issue when I installed WebView.

To fix it, you need to update your `compileSdkVersion` to 29. While you are at it, you might as well update the `buildToolsVersion`. You can do that by changing these lines in your project's `/android/build.gradle` file.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        …
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
        compileSdkVersion = 29
        …
    }
…
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Ananthu, I re-implemented the project using adding the extensions you suggested, and it compiled successfully.

Comment: 2024 February

I updated the build tools to 34.0.0 n the compile sdk version to 34. But I am still getting this error saying there is an issue with webview.

Answer (score 4):

No need to change your "compileSdkVersion" and "buildToolsVersion". Just install the WebView version 12.1.0, That's it! Worked for me!

First uninstall any previous versions using:

```
npm uninstall react-native-webview
```

Now install 12.1.0 version:

```
npm install react-native-webview@12.1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

update WebView
`yarn add react-native-webview`

Comment: This worked for me